# PHP interactive interpreter: Delete and Ctrl +Aarrows keys don't work properly

Tags: command-line, keyboard, php, php-cli

When running PHP interactive interpreter with:

```
php -a
```

<kbd>Delete</kbd> button doesn't work (produces `~` instead), jumping over words with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> doesn't work either (`;5D` and `;5C`, respectively). It annoys me a lot - I use `php -a` every day. 
Worth noting, that other interpreters (irb, ipython, etc.) work good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are still experiencing this issue, I raised a bug at php.net and got an answer there - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65191&thanks=6

My ~/.editrc:

```
    bind \\e[3~ ed-delete-next-char
    bind \\e[1;5C vi-next-word
    bind \\e[1;5D vi-prev-word
```